# Codeigniter calling model method from another model causes error

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model, controller

I have a controller:

```
class Blah extends Controller
{
     function Blah()
      {
        $this->load->model('baga_model');
      }
}
```

then comes baga_model:

```
 class Baga_model extends Model
    {
      function do_it()
       {
         echo "BOOM!";
       }
    }
```

..and

```
class Blah_model extends Model
        {
          function some_action()
           {
             $this->baga_model->do_it();
           }
        }
```

So .. when in *blah_model* I call *$this->baga_model->do_it()* I get an error :
**Call to a member function do_it() on a non-object**

I just can't understand why.... I know it must work, I did something similar before..
Thanks

Comment: What  is your problem do you need to call model or function from model

Comment: Thanks . I need to call method of baga_model when I am in blah_model..

Comment: You need to extend `CI_Model` and `CI_Controller`

Comment: You mention `blah_model` yet your code only shows `blah`, a controller. Please show the correct classes

Comment: Thanks Philip, yes I know...It's just for a a quick reference.

Comment: Yes Steve I was about to add blah model , but web form was complaining about: "too much of code..." It allowed me edit though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I had to load `baga_model` in `blah_model` constructor. This way it works.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function test()
    {
        $this->load->model('baga_model');
        $this->baga_model->do_it();
    }
```

Model

```
class baga_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function do_it()
   {
     echo $this->bar("BOOM!");
   }
```

Your not loading your required model inside your model:

```
 class Blah_model extends CI_Model
    {
$this->baga_model = $this->load->model('baga_model', true);
        public function some_action()
       {
         $this->baga_model->do_it();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Soul, but I need to call baga_model->do_it() while in blah model not the constructor...

Comment: Sorry I don't get it... I am loading $this->load->model('baga_model'); in Blah_controller... Also I have tried to load it just before calling do_it() function.... still same result..

Comment: just use $this->do_it @Dims